# Magento2 : How to add custom block on product page

Tags: product, magento-2.1.7

I want to add my custom template on product page just like `$this->getChildHtml('custom_product_info')`.

As in magento1.9 to use `$this->getChildHtml('custom_product_info')` we add layout xml like below :

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info"> 
        <block type="core/template"  name="custom_product_info" template="custom.phtml"/>  
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

What is the xml and process to add custom template in Magento2.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info">
            <block class="{Vendor}\{Module}\Block\Catalog\Product\View\{Class}" name="{your.block.name}" template="{Vendor}_{Module}::{template_name}.phtml">
                <!-- If you have any arguments to pass -->
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="{argument_name}" xsi:type="string">{Your argument}</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: For `class="{Vendor}\{Module}\Block\Catalog\Product\View\{Class}"` should I create a block class, please post a example for block class.

Comment: You should be able to use this block: `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Comment: How can I get `$product` in custom template file?

Comment: Follow this tutorial: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-current-category-current-product/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add this custom block via Custom module,
Then create `catalog_product_view.xml` at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{moduleName}/view/frontend/layout`,.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info">
            <block class="{Vendor}\{Module}\Block\{BLOCK_CLASSS}" name="{block.name.inlayout}"  as="{name_aliase_path}"
template="{Vendor}_{ModuleName}::{YourTemaplte}.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then you can call your block via at code at form.phtml at

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml({name_aliase_path}) ?>
```

Comment: Our custom phtml file will be called as childHtml of any another phtml or we can only call in that particular layout  ( `catalog_product_view.xml` ) only which we created our custom phtml file

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block.name"  as="block.alias"
template="{Vendor}_{ModuleName}::{YourTemaplte}.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="{argument_name}" template="template_name.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceContainer name="content">

            <block class="Xcommerce\Category\Block\Overview" name="overview" 
            template="X2commerce_Category::custom.phtml">
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
```