# Read product attribute from phtml file - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, product, php, attributes, phtml

I have created a simple phtml file to add a 3D viewer in the product page using the following code. I have also created a custom attribute for the product, called `model_file_name` in which I type the name of the `glb` file I want to display.

If I replace `FILENAMEHERE` with an existing file name, the 3D model is shown in the page, the only problem I have is passing a file name specific for every product.

I have found some examples about how to read an attribute, but none of them refers to the code included in a .phtml file. The sample below is using the ProductRepository, but the code **does not work**, the error is: `Notice: Undefined variable: productRepository`

How do I read a custom attribute from a .phtml file ?

Here is the list of the files I have created, they are stored in the  `./app/design/frontend/[CUSTOM_THEME]/theme/Magento_Catalog/` folder

file `Block/Model3D.php`:

```
<?php
class Model3D extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getProductBySku($sku)
    {
        return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    }
}
?>
```

file `layout/catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
            <block class="VrMur\theme\Magento_Catalog\Block\Model3D" name="custom.text" template="Magento_Catalog::view/customtext.phtml" after="gallery"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

file `templates/view/customtext.phtml`:

```
<?php
  $product = $block->getProductBySku("PRODUCTSKU");
  $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
  foreach($attributes as $a)
  {
      echo $a->getName()."\n";
  }
?>

<!-- Import the component -->
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .3d-model {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<!-- Use it like any other HTML element -->
    <p>3D Model: </p>
    <model-viewer style="width: 100%; height: 600px; top: 0px; background-color: 0xeeefff;" 
    id="3d-model" class="3d-model" alt="3d model" 
    src="http://vrmur.local/media/models/FILENAMEHERE" ar environment-image="" 
    poster="" shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls>
    </model-viewer>
```

Comment: plz share code you used for adding phtml

Comment: @Pawan I have updated the question with the missing code

Comment: Added my answer, plz give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer would be loading **product repository** via **object manager**, you can technically do this in a template but that's bad practice

So, let's work a bit

You should first add a new block in product page layout, where you call your template. You can get more info about this [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219813/magento2-how-to-add-custom-block-on-product-page)

For that block you might want to use your own custom block class. Here you a have a [nice tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html#step-2-create-layout-file-xml) for that

And then, you'd want to implement a `getProductBySku()` method in your block, where you make that product repository call. So, your custom block would be something like this

```
class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getProductBySku($sku)
    {
        return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    }
}
```

And then, in your template you can get the product this way

```
$product = $block->getProductBySku("PRODUCTSKU");
```

Comment: I have tested your solution, but I still get the same error. I've updated the question with the missing code.

Comment: The block should be placed in app/code folder, in your custom module

Answer (score 0):

If you added layout in `catalog_product_view.xml` i.e. need customization on PDP page. You can change phtml block class to `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`.

In phtml file use:

```
// get current product
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>

// get attribute value from product like

<?php echo $_product->getModelFileName(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('model_file_name'); ?>
```